# PHP Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap

I've following problem with my php script:

> PHP Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in ....

`ldap_connect()` says "Success" but `ldap_bind()` fails, how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connect opens the session.  Bind is what actually authenticates you.  Thus you connected but did not login with valid credentials.

Comment: This answer is not correct. I am able to get PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in ... on one server while I am able to use the same credentials to get `true` as result of the bind on my local machine.

Comment: The `ldap_connect` method does not connect or open a session to the server. From the docs **Note: This function does not open a connection. It checks whether the given parameters are plausible and can be used to open a connection as soon as one is needed.**. The act of doing an `ldap_bind` will initiate the connection, so will a `ldap_start_tls`.

Comment: It's not necessary that the credentials are invalid, there can be other issues too as stated in some answers.

Answer (score 13):

Had this error on RHEL7 ( CentOS7 ) due to SELinux restricting ports HTTPD can use.

LDAP ports 389 and 636 are not on the default allow list, you can unblock with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

You can test for the restriction by trying a socket to the LDAP server:

```
fsockopen('LDAP-Server-IP', 389);
```

It will give 'Permission Denied' showing it's blocked and not a credentials issue.

Also check your SELinux audit log file for other things being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

the ldap_bind() function asks for a three parameters:

1. a resource id
2. a rdn
3. a password associated with the rdn the rdn and password are optional

if you bind using only the resource id :-

```
// $ldap=ladap_connect(*hostname*,*port*);  
// ldap_connect() returns a resource id
ldap_bind() returns a boolean value(true or false)  
ldap_bind($ladp); //annonymous bind    
$lb=ldap_bind($ldap,"uid=xxx,ou=something,o=hostname.com","password"); //used to authenticate
```

this should work if not then you are using invalid credentials.

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your answer, especially use list and code formatting - see [editting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @ObenSonne Please improve the spelling of your comment, or the answer itself.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Thanks for pointing that out. You may want to pay your attention to http://stackoverflow.com/review/

Answer (score 1):

Sometime the problem will depend of your environment(Linux, Windows...)
Try to bind with one of this options:

```
$connect = ldap_connect("ldap://".$ldap_server);
$auth_user = 'CN=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=com';
$bind = ldap_bind($connect, $auth_user , $auth_pass);
```

or

```
$bind = ldap_bind($connect, 'YourDomaine\\'.$auth_user , $auth_pass);
```