# PHP on CentOS 7: LDAP could not bind to the server

Tags: php, centos, ldap

I have the following code

```php
    public function openConnection()
    {
        $this->ldapServerHandle = ldap_connect(ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->host);

        $bindDN = ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->serviceAccount->bindDN;

        if ($this->ldapServerHandle) {
            $this->ldapBindHandle = ldap_bind(
                $this->ldapServerHandle,
                $bindDN,
                ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->serviceAccount->password
            );
            if (!$this->ldapBindHandle) {
                $errorMsg = "LDAP::__construct(): Could not bind the service account ".$bindDN;
                LoggerH::emergency($errorMsg);
                throw new LDAPException($errorMsg);
            }
        } else {
            $errorMsg = "LDAP::__construct(): Could not connect to the LDAP server ".ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->host;
            LoggerH::emergency($errorMsg);
            throw new LDAPException($errorMsg);
        }
    }
```

## The issue

I have this error causing me headaches since this morning:
`Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server [...]`

Everything worked fine on Windows, when I executed the code on our CentOS production server, it stopped working.

## What I have already  checked

- OpenLDAP is installed and enabled
- The LDAP server is reachable from the CentOS server (Kerberos is experiencing no issues on the same machine)

## What I have already tried

- Re-installed the `php-ldap` extension
- Checked the credentials and the address a milion times

## Additional information

- ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->host returns something like "adserver.ourcompany.com", which is the address of our LDAP server
- ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->serviceAccount->bindDN returns a valid bind DN
- ConfigH::getConfig()->ldap->serviceAccount->password returns the password of the service account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The solution

Who uses CentOS gets SELinux, yay.
After digging even deeper in Google (such as page 4 of results) and Stackoverflow, I found the issue to be caused by SELinux restricting `httpd` to communicate over some ports despite the firewall being configured to allow it, including the LDAP one(s).

To allow `httpd` to communicate over these ports, run the following command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

(Original solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309372/php-warning-ldap-bind-unable-to-bind-to-server-cant-contact-ldap-server/) (WhoIsRich's answer))

Comment: A whole day is saved! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear ! :)